# Is there a way to do the Ruby each_slice in Java 8?

Tags: java, ruby

If I have an array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And want to split this into to groups of 3, I can use .each_slice(3) as follows

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(3).to_a => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Is there a way I can do something similar in Java 8?

[Ruby enumerable each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

Comment: It's 09/2020 and Java's API is still lacking this, while this data driven world needs more and more batches & chunks. I miss Ruby every time I use Java.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
public static int[][] slice(int[] arr, int n) {
    return IntStream.range(0, (int) Math.ceil((double) arr.length / n))
            .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i * n, Math.min((i + 1) * n, arr.length)))
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Comment: @akhil_mittal you need Java 8 for this

Comment: @Flown It complains of cyclic inference on my machine. And yes I am on Java 8.

Comment: @akhil_mittal Where is the cyclic inference? I'm running Java 1.8.0_51

Comment: @Flown I am using JDK 1.8.0_31

Comment: @akhil_mittal Again: Where is the cyclic inference?

Comment: @Flown: IntelliJ complains of cyclic reference in `mapToObj` statement.

Comment: @akhil_mittal Compile it with your command line and see what happens. Obviously there is no cyclic reference in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is, but there's no elegant one-method way of doing it that I'm aware of.  You'd need to write your own array slice method, something like this (nasty, inelegant way):

```
public static int[][] slice(int[] source, int n) {
    List<int[]> results = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    int len = (source.length % n == 0 ? source.length/n : source.length / n + 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        results.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(source, i * n, (i+1 == len ? source.length : (i+1)*len)));
    }

    return results.toArray(new int[][]{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have liked the solution proposed by Flown above but somehow it does not compile in my IntelliJ. I have used his solution only to modify it a little and have written method `sliceUsingJavaStreams` below. Another thing with my code is it works even when array cannot be sliced completely e.g an array with elements `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` will be sliced as `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]` in the following code:

### Without Using Streams:

```
public static int[][] slice(int[] array, int sliceSize) {
        int slicesCount = (int) Math.ceil(array.length/(double)sliceSize);
        int[][] results = new int[slicesCount][];
        int[] sliceArray;
        int index = 0;
        for(int i=array.length; i>0; i=i-sliceSize) {
            int start = array.length-i;
            int last = ((start+sliceSize) < array.length)? (start+sliceSize) : (array.length);
            sliceArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array,start,last);
            results[index++] = sliceArray;
        }
        return results;
    }
```

### Using Streams:

```
public static int[][] sliceUsingJavaStreams(int[] arr, int n) {
        return IntStream.range(0, (int) Math.ceil(arr.length / (double) n))
                .mapToObj(new IntFunction<int[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public int[] apply(int i) {
                        return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i * n, Math.min((i + 1) * n, arr.length));
                    }
                }).toArray(int[][]::new);
    }
```

Now I can test them as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        final int n = 3;
        int[][] slicedArrayOne = slice(array,3);
        int[][] slicedArrayTwo = sliceUsingJavaStreams(array,3);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(slicedArrayOne));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(slicedArrayTwo));
    }
```

And the output is:

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind depending on the excellent Guava library, you can use [Lists.partition](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)) or [Iterables.partition](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition(java.lang.Iterable,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be hard to add.

Iterate the input. Every n elements add a new bucke. Add the item there:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> eachSlice(List<T> input, int size) {

    List<List<T>> r = new ArrayList<List<T>>();

    for( int i = 0 ; i < input.size(); i++ ) { // iterate input
        if ( i % size == 0 ) {                 // every n elements
            r.add(new ArrayList<T>());         // add bucket
        }
        r.get(r.size()-1).add(input.get(i));   // add current element to bucket
    }

    return r;
}
```

The you can `import static` this function and use it, e.g.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static something.Util.eachSlice;
class Main {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
        List<List<Integer>> output  = eachSlice( input , 3);
        out.println( output );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```